# Create Pandas data frame with statistics from PySpark data frame

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have big PySpark data frame that looks like this:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, to_timestamp

data = [('2010-09-12 0', 'x1', 13), 
        ('2010-09-12 0', 'x2', 12), 
        ('2010-09-12 2', 'x3', 23), 
        ('2010-09-12 4', 'x1', 22), 
        ('2010-09-12 4', 'x2', 32), 
        ('2010-09-12 4', 'x3', 7), 
        ('2010-09-12 6', 'x3', 24),
        ('2010-09-12 16', 'x3', 34),]

columns = ['timestamp', 'category', 'value']
df =spark.createDataFrame(data=data, schema=columns)
df = df.withColumn('ts', to_timestamp(col('timestamp'), 'yyyy-MM-dd H')).drop(col('timestamp'))
df.show()
```

```
+--------+-----+-------------------+
|category|value|                 ts|
+--------+-----+-------------------+
|      x1|   13|2010-09-12 00:00:00|
|      x2|   12|2010-09-12 00:00:00|
|      x3|   23|2010-09-12 02:00:00|
|      x1|   22|2010-09-12 04:00:00|
|      x2|   32|2010-09-12 04:00:00|
|      x3|    7|2010-09-12 04:00:00|
|      x3|   24|2010-09-12 06:00:00|
|      x3|   34|2010-09-12 16:00:00|
+--------+-----+-------------------+
```

The timestamp in column `ts` is increasing at every exact 2-hour interval(for eg. `0`, `2`, ..., `22`)

I want to extract the `average`, `min`, `max`, `median` of column `value` by the `ts` timestamp, and put these statistics into a `pandas` data frame as following:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

start_ts = datetime.datetime(year=2010, month=2, day=1, hour=0)
end_ts = datetime.datetime(year=2022, month=6, day=1, hour=22)
```

```
ts                      average   min    max   median 
...
2010-09-12 00:00:00     12.5      12     13    12.5
2010-09-12 02:00:00     23        23     23    23
2010-09-12 04:00:00     20.3      7      32    22
2010-09-12 06:00:00     24        24     24    24
2010-09-12 16:00:00     34        34     34    34
...
```

What would be an economical way to do this, minimizing the number of iterations over the `pyspark` dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should calculate the accurate median, but you shouldn't be using accurate median for very big groups of data.

Also, you can filter data without `datetime` module.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = (df
    .filter(F.col('ts').between('2010-02-01', '2022-06-01'))
    .groupBy('ts').agg(
        F.round(F.mean('value'), 1).alias('average'),
        F.min('value').alias('min'),
        F.max('value').alias('max'),
        F.expr('percentile(value, .5)').alias('median'),
    )
)
pdf = df.toPandas()
print(pdf)
#                    ts  average  min  max  median
# 0 2010-09-12 02:00:00     23.0   23   23    23.0
# 1 2010-09-12 00:00:00     12.5   12   13    12.5
# 2 2010-09-12 06:00:00     24.0   24   24    24.0
# 3 2010-09-12 16:00:00     34.0   34   34    34.0
# 4 2010-09-12 04:00:00     20.3    7   32    22.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Aggregate then convert the result into pandas:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.groupby("ts").agg(
    F.avg("value").alias("average"),
    F.min("value").alias("min"),
    F.max("value").alias("max"),
    F.percentile_approx("value", 0.5).alias("median")
)

result = df1.toPandas()

#                    ts    average  min  max  median
# 0 2010-09-12 00:00:00  12.500000   12   13      12
# 1 2010-09-12 02:00:00  23.000000   23   23      23
# 2 2010-09-12 04:00:00  20.333333    7   32      22
# 3 2010-09-12 06:00:00  24.000000   24   24      24
# 4 2010-09-12 16:00:00  34.000000   34   34      34
```

Comment: Thanks. Both solutions look similar and I appreciate that your response was the first. There was some additional useful info in ZygD's response that I could use.